# invalid number value for power of 18

Tags: web3js

Using web3js v1.2.1

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0x29...');
const amount = 1 * 10 ** 18;
const data = contract.methods.transfer(recipient, amount).encodeABI();
```

I get error :

```
invalid number value (arg="value", coderType="uint256", val


 reason: 'invalid number value',
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  arg: 'value',
  coderType: 'uint256',
  value: 1000000000000000000 }
```

---

This should work:

```
const amount = web3.utils.toHex(1e18)
```

Comment: use web3 method to convert ether to wei

Answer (score 2):

javascript cannot handle those big numbers, Use the method web3.utils.toWei(number [, unit]).

```
const amount = web3.utils.toWei(1, 'ether');
```

Comment: Error: Please pass numbers as strings or BigNumber objects to avoid precision errors.

Comment: vlt web3.utils.toBN(web3.utils.toWei(1, 'ether'));

Comment: oder (web3.utils.toWei(1, 'ether')).toString());

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a string or a `BN` object, not an integer.

Also note that this specific integer (`10 ** 18`) is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` and should therefore not be used for any other purpose.

Here are a few options which you can choose from:

```
const amount = "1e18";
const amount = Web3.utils.toBN("1e18");
const amount = Web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(18);
```

Or with a variable `x = 18` (which you can change of course):

```
const amount = `1e${x}`;
const amount = Web3.utils.toBN(`1e${x}`);
const amount = Web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(x);
```

Comment: All the above give me the same error. or error :  num.bitLength is not a function

Comment: @Alvin: Well maybe you are passing `recipient` and `amount` in the wrong order. It's hard to say, because you haven't posted your implementation of function `transfer` (the standard function indeed uses this order of parameters, but perhaps you've implemented your own version, who knows...).

Comment: how would toBN ever work if you have a float number. Let's say you want to send 10000.123 tokens with 8 decimals. You won't be able to do Web3.utils.toBN(10000.123).pow(8) as toBN only accepts whole numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert it toLocaleString("fullwide", { useGrouping: false })) and You will get numbers as string.

```
console.log((1000000 * 1e18).toLocaleString("fullwide", { useGrouping: false }));
```